# Proper use of subscribe() to Observable with entity representation

Tags: angular, subscribe

**I struggle making a simple Service - Component connection when using my own entity representation as .ts file:**

**news.ts file:**

```
export interface News {
    id: number,
    something: String
}
```

**Im passing this to service:**

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { News } from '../interfaces/news';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SomeService {
  private newsUrl = '...';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { 
  }

  public getNews(): Observable<News> {
    return this.http.get<News>('...');
  }
}
```

**And when I try to pass this to component like this:**

```
export class SomeComponent {
  public news: News[] = [];

  constructor(private newsService: SomeService) {}

  public getNews(): void {
    this.newsService.getNews().subscribe(
      (response: News[]) => { this.newsArray = response }
... error
    )
  }
```

**I get "No overload matches this call.."
Its probably trivial but im newb**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check this part:

```js
public getNews(): Observable<News> {
    return this.http.get<News>('...');
  }
```

Here if you are getting Array of News then it may be required to put array of News in the get call as well.

I hope this works. Thank you

Comment: Thank you good sir, but when im using arrays I can't get any property from it, like it would be another type (not type News). For eg <div>{{newsArray.id}}</div> throws "No such property

Comment: @Dzik I would recommend using type any for a while and doing a console log on what is getting returned by your get call. You can console.log(response) in the subscription. This way you can get the structure of what is returned. I hope this helps. Also, i may require more information if you need further help.

Comment: Thx, ill do so :)

Answer (score 0):

Try making this
Instead of:

```
return this.http.get<News>(....);
Just use the non-generic one:

return this.http.get(...);
```

Comment: Thx, works with <any> but im not sure about the outcome

Comment: you are welcome I'll be grateful if you mark this answer as useful :D

Answer (score 0):

You have a type mismatch between your service call and your subscription: `News` vs `News[]`.

Since `getNews()` is defined to return a type of `News`, the subscription will expect to get type of `News`.  However, in the subscribe, you are indicating type of `News[]`, this is the reason for your error.

In reality, the call is most likely returning `News[]`, so you should probably change the type in the method definition:

```
  public getNews(): Observable<News[]> {
    return this.http.get<News[]>('...');
  }
```

> when im using arrays I can't get any property from it, like it would be another type

Are you using `*ngFor` in the template to iterate the array?  If so, you should be able to access the properties:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let news of newsArray">{{ news.something }}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I can't get access to newsArray this way, should I maybe use different declaration/with access modifier?

Comment: When I run plain {{newsArray}} I get [object Object],[object Object].. but it doesn't parse itself. Is there and option to maybe parse it to News after receiving and than use in html

Comment: Sorry, I put “this.newsArray” should have been just “newsArray” in the template. I updated example code.

Comment: Still I can't use that property in html;

Comment: Still I can't use that property in html; This is what I get in console when I swap 
>>> this.newsArray = response 
WITH 
>>> console.log(response) 
In NewsComponent getNews ... subscribe 

>>>Array (4)
0 {id: 1, title: "typ", content: "content", imgURL: null, readMoreURL: null, …}
... 

So it is an Object (Not News Object) but I can't get its values anyway via {{object.something}} in html